# Trying to find the average value of a column 'salary' from table 'ei_benefits' for only the 14 highest values in the column 'salary'

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying find the average value of a column 'salary' from table 'ei_benefits' for only the 14 highest values in the column 'salary'. I'm using phpmyadmin and this is what I'm using.

```
select avg(salary) 
from ei_benefits 
where salary IN (select salary from ei_benefits order by salary desc limit 14)
```

The error I'm getting is this.

> #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Would this be correct in a different version of mysql? Also, could someone please help me find the right way to process the query for the version I'm using?

Comment: If you just searched for the error message you would have found dozens of similar questions.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I'm new so wasn't sure about where to look. A lot of stuff here is really confusing. I found the answer. Thank you for your help.